Why is the cloudwatch metric not enabled?
I'm attempting to create an alarm in Cloudwatch for account billing. I'm following the instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/gs_monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html
When I select a metric (billing), the button to enable this is disabled. See image. Why isn't this enabled? I am selecting a metric (Estimated Charges), but this doesn't seem to be recognized.


Check if the selected region in the top right of the console is the same as the region selected for the metric. in your case us-east-1
